# Save uiview as specified size

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, retina-display

I have an `uiimageview` that is 600x600 and a `uitexview` loaded in a 200x200 uiview.

I would like to export this `uiview` to 600x600, same as the `uiimageview` size.

However If I use the code below I can only generate a size of 400x400, that is the retina size of the `uiview`.

Is there any code I can achieve this?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputView.bounds.size, outputView.opaque, 2);
[outputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: did you try applying a transform to the outputView? i.e. `outputView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the bounds of the view to what you need?

```
outputView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,600,600);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputView.bounds.size, outputView.opaque, 2);     [outputView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
outputView.bound = ... original bounds here ...
```

If the internal view is set to be resized automatically, this should work seamlessly. Otherwise, you could change the frame of the internal view as well.

Comment: Thanks the outputView works. I've applied the bounds to `uitextview` but it didn't change at all, any idea?

Comment: I think you can scale the text view if you want it to be bigger; or you change the frame and font size...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [UIImage category](https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize) of AliSoftware to resize it